# Can not load kivy file from kv variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

So I'm working on my first app and when learning about kivy and watching youtube videos I was seeing different ways people would load in their KV file and one was putting in in a variable and returning it from the build method. Anytime I do this, no errors are necessarily thrown but it doesn't load the window properly and it makes no sense why the KV file isnt loading. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it, the code is below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager



class LoginLayout(Widget):
    def login(self, **kwargs):
        print("Login function working")
        username = self.ids.username.text
        password = self.ids.password.text
        print(username)
        print(password)

kv = Builder.load_file('loginScreen.kv')


class LoginScreen(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv


app = LoginScreen()
app.run()
```

kv file

```
<LoginLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: 'Username'

        TextInput:
            id: username
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (.5, .3)
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : .5}


        Label:
            text: 'Password'

        TextInput:
            id: password
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (.5, .3)
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : .5}

        Button:
            text: 'Login'
            size_hint: (.2, .8)
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5}
            on_release: root.login()

        Button:
            text: 'Create Account'
            size_hint: (.2, .8)
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5}


        Button:
            text: 'Forgot login Info'
            size_hint: (.2, .8)
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `kv` does not define a root widget, it only defines rules for how to build the `LoginLayout`. An easy fix is to remove the `<>` from around `LoginLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Kivy is pretty fun once you get the little stuff down.